# Framework 0.130 seconds slower than pure PHP - bad?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, lumen

i've ported a simple PHP project to Laravel and Lumen.

The running times (tested with webpagetest.org) until are elements are loaded on the user's machine:

PHP-Pur: 0.332 Sec
Lumen: 0.363 Sec
Laravel: 0.468 Sec

Does it make a "big" difference for the user when the Laravel alternative takes 0.130 sec longer than the pure PHP project?

Thanks!

Comment: That depend on what the the customer expects?

Comment: Did you run the tests in a dev environment where cache is disabled for example? 0.332 s is a long time for pure PHP.

Comment: Depends also on the number of times this process is repeated. You see... 0,130 seconds multiplied by a million times would be a long, long time!

Comment: @A.L It's not the running time of the script, it's for the whole site (php/html/images/scripts).

Comment: @Chama, if my answer was helpful, please choose my answer as best answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how do you run tests. There is built-in caching system in modern frameworks, which doesn't work in dev environment, for example. Yes frameworks are slower, but the difference is not so dramatical.

There were a lot of benchmarks and talks about the subject. Google for them if you're really interested.

Comment: `php artisan optimize` also can help in certain cases

Answer (score 0):

This question is off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming, you're asking about user experience.

Anyway here are some facts:

> - 47% of consumers expect a web page to load in 2 seconds or less.
> - 40% of people abandon a website that takes more than 3 seconds to load.
> - A 1 second delay in page response can result in a 7% reduction in conversions.

[Source](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/).

> People will visit a Web site less often if it is slower than a close competitor by more than 250 milliseconds (a millisecond is a thousandth of a second).

[Source](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/01/technology/impatient-web-users-flee-slow-loading-sites.html).